# Looping software for recording

Tags: software, looping

There is recording hardware that consistently loops while the musician successively records new tracks. For example, first, the musician records the drum, the machine then repeats the recording infinitely while the musician can record the guitar. Step by step, the sound is enriched by more instruments or vocals. Additionally, there are buttons to (de-)activate certain tracks.

Is there a free software implementation of this looper hardware that records MIDI and runs on Linux?

Comment: Please take the time to take the [Tour](https://music.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [Help pages](https://music.stackexchange.com/help), especially [What topics can I ask about here?](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)